# Terminating vs non-terminating link apollo link?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

```
const httpLink = ...

const errorLink = ...

const link = ApolloLink.from([errorLink, httpLink]);
```

> When doing so, be careful to chain the control flow in the correct
>   order. The apollo-link-http is called a terminating link because it
>   turns an operation into a result that usually occurs from a network
>   request. On the other side, the apollo-link-error is a non-terminating
>   link. It only enhances your terminating link with features, since a
>   terminating link has to be last entity in the control flow chain.

So here I didn't get the difference between terminating link and non-terminating link??

*source: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-graphql-apollo-tutorial/*

Answer (score 0):

"Simply enough, the terminating link is the one that doesn't use the forward argument, but instead turns the operation into the result directly." as stated at: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/overview/

In short, your link should either pass to next link in chain by invoking forward (non-terminating) or return some data (terminating) (non-terminating).